# how to define different price and discount price by (color + size) in zencart?

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

how to define different price and discount price by (color + size) in zencart?
defaultly, zencart can define a product price base on attributes, such as color .
but I can not find how to set defferent attribute with random discount price. can  any one tell me how to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is rather vague, I would suggest you begin with the Attributes Controller in the Admin area.

[Zen Cart Attributes Controller](http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Admin_-_Catalog_-_Attributes_Controller)

This area allows you the freedom to apply a wide variety of discount pricing and attribute pricing for your products.